# How to return a value from a matrix in java

Tags: java

I was reading about matrx in java and I found this method in my course page :

```
public int getSeatStatus(int row, char ch) { // Returns the status of the seat (row, ch)
return seats[row][(ch - ’A’)].getStatus();
 }
```

I do not understand how the method works .. as you can see that ch is not an index so why do they use it as an index ?

Can we rewrite this code in another simple way ?
for example I tried to rewrite it like this :

```
public int getSeatStatus(int row, char ch){
    int col = 0;
    if (ch == 'A') {
        col=0;
    } else if (ch == 'B') {
        col=1;
    }
    return s[row][col].getStatus();

}
```

Am I doing right ?
Thanks

Comment: Rewriting it like you do is quite unneccessary since `'A' - 'A' = 0`. note that you can easily cast an `char` to an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it like that... If you have two 'ch' objects it's managable with if statements, but what if you have a 100? It would mean a unmaintable amount of if statements.

If you cast char 'A' to an int, the value is 65. By doing
`ch - 'A'` you get 65 - 65 corresponding with index 0.
If you cast char 'B' to an int, the value is 66. By doing `ch - 'A'` you get 66 - 65 corresponding with 1.

Your first example is in fact a better way to do this, and will work, even if the seats are "numbered" A till Z.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a Character into an Integer. So you can also use it as an index.
For example the output for `System.out.println(0 + 'A')` is 65.

Answer (score 1):

According to the ASCII standard the letter `A` has an integer value of `65` and `Z`  of `90`.

So, if you subtract `A` from the value of the given parameter, you get a value:

```
('B' - 'A') = (66 - 65) = 1
('F' - 'A') = (70 - 65) = 5
```

If you wanted to rewrite the rule for the whole alphabet, you would have to write 26 cases of recurring code.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `char` is a numeric type. When you do `char - ’A’`, you operate with [unicode code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). In case of `'A' - 'A'`, result is 0, when `'B' - 'A'` result is 1, etc. It gives array indexes.